# Mongoid relating one object to two different objects of the same class using has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have see solutions to this sort of issue with 1:N, but they dont seem to read across to 1:1, this is using MongoDB 1.8, Mongoid 2.0.0.rc.8, Rails 3.0.5

```
class Coach  
  include Mongoid::Document 
  field :name, :type => String 
  belongs_to :coached, :class_name => Team, :inverse_of => :coach, :foreign_key => "coach_id" 
  belongs_to :assisted, :class_name => Team, :inverse_of => :assist, :foreign_key => "assist_id" 
end 


class Team 
  include Mongoid::Document 
  field :name, :type => String 
  has_one :coach, :class_name => Coach, :inverse_of => :coached 
  has_one :assist, :class_name => Coach, :inverse_of => :assisted 
end
```

Then I start and Rails Console session and:

```
irb(main):001:0> c = Coach.new(:name => "Tom")  
=> #<Coach _id: da18348d298ca47ad000001, _type: nil, _id: BSON::ObjectId('4da18348d298ca47ad000001'), name: "Tom", coach_id: nil, assist_id: nil> 

irb(main):002:0> a = Coach.new(:name => "Dick") 
=> #<Coach _id: 4da18352d298ca47ad000002, _type: nil, _id: BSON::ObjectId('4da18352d298ca47ad000002'), name: "Dick", coach_id: nil, assist_id: nil> 

irb(main):003:0> t = Team.new(:name => "Allstars") 
=> #<Team _id: 4da18362d298ca47ad000003, _type: nil, _id: BSON::ObjectId('4da18362d298ca47ad000003'), name: "Allstars"> 

irb(main):005:0> t.coach = c 
NoMethodError: undefined method `constantize' for Coach:Class 

irb(main):005:0> c.coached = t 
NoMethodError: undefined method `constantize' for Team:Class
```

any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're referencing the class `Team` when defining `Coach`, but the class does not yet exist. 
You have two options:

- Declare the `class_name` as a String instead of the constant e.g. `:class_name => 'Team'` (preferred, see [gist](https://gist.github.com/919170))
- Completely remove `:class_name => Team` option and let Mongoid figure out the correct classes participating in the association. **There is one caveat:** You will need to make sure that the class `Team` is declared before the class `Coach` (the order of loading your source codes now matters, so this solution is not ideal)

Comment: +1 for above answer, if anyone sees error where it complains about NoMethodError, then it most likely related to loading issue. Declaring  class_name as string solves the problem.